# Fsck on a Window 10 hd

Tags: boot, windows-10, fsck

I answer lots of newbie questions on SO, I know how painful it can be; please excuse my ignorance with Ubuntu.

I have a boot issue with a Windows 10 laptop (I get the logo then black screen with no opportunity to enter Startup Repair etc).

As the laptop had a HD issue a few months ago, **I want to run a `CHKDSK` / `FSCK` on the Windows Drive C.**

I have Ubuntu 17.04 on a USB stick (and also installed alongside Window Boot Manager). **I've been trying to follow tutorials to run `fsck` but I'm stuck...**

I don't know if what I'm getting is an error or if I'm doing something wrong.

I assume this screen pic will show you what I have and what I tried:

[image: img]

I assume I am using the correct drive...  "the big one with Windows on it".

(Sorry for the crappy pic, I'm reduced to a cell as my only device...)

Thoughts/suggestions?

---

**Edit:** `ntfsfix` result

[image: img2]

Comment: One more thing, a Longshot:. If not the hard drive I have a hunch that the sound hardware could be causing the problem due to how it first crashed and odd chirps its now making at boot. Is there any way I can disable all sound-related hardware via Ubuntu and then attempt to boot Windows? (Sry I guess that should be a separate question)

Comment: No, you can't.  You need a running Windows for that.

Answer (score 2):

The fsck tool `ntfsfix` is for scanning NTFS.

Mind that this is not a 100% functional replacement for the tools Windows offers. It will only fix [common errors](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ntfsfix.8.html):

> ntfsfix is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems.  ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk.  It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows. You may run ntfsfix on an NTFS volume if you think it was damaged by Windows or some other way and it cannot be mounted.

You should repair Windows from Windows. Windows also offers a repair option on their installation medium.

===

> SYNOPSIS

```
ntfsfix [options] device
```

> OPTIONS
>
> Below is a summary of all the options that ntfsfix accepts. Nearly all options have two equivalent names. The short name is preceded by - and the long name is preceded by --. Any single letter options, that don't take an argument, can be combined into a single command, e.g. -fv is equivalent to -f -v. Long named options can be abbreviated to any unique prefix of their name.

```
-b, --clear-bad-sectors
   Clear the list of bad sectors. This is useful after cloning 
   an old disk with bad sectors to a new disk. 
-d, --clear-dirty
   Clear the volume dirty flag if the volume can be fixed and mounted. 
   If the option is not present or the volume cannot be fixed, 
   the dirty volume flag is set to request a volume checking at next mount. 
-h, --help
    Show a list of options with a brief description of each one. 
-n, --no-action
    Do not write anything, just show what would have been done. 
-V, --version
    Show the version number, copyright and license
```

Comment: I wish I could do this through Windows but that's the problem. Just a general check would be fine. Is the syntax the same as I was using on fsck?  Ie, umount then ntfsfix with the device name I was using?

Comment: Yes; I added the options and syntax ;)

Comment: Incidentally it was this article that have me the impression fsck was the right tool, I guess I misunderstood...  https://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-chkdsk-ubuntu-54071.html

Comment: one more pic for you, added to my question. I assume my first attempt failed only because I didn't use `sudo` and the second attempt says everything's fine with that drive... And so there's nothing else I can check via Ubuntu... Is that correct?  (I didn't attempt to unmount but I suppose it was still unmounted from before?)